# How to improve classes with common code?

Tags: java, optimization

I have two classes that have some code in common. Pseudo-code:

- optain the validator
- apply class-specific validation (one might validate an address, other a payment)
- collect errors from validation and give user feedback

Now only the middle part with specific validation is different, and the "surrounding" code is the same in each class.

How could I best improve this code? Create an abstract superclass that provides two methods for optaining the validator and for collecting the errors, and then call these methods in implementation classes each?

Problem: both classes extend different legacy classes, that's why I cannot create an abstract superclass here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about composition? You don't need to have the classes extend the legacy classes, just make them members of your validator object.

```
class Validator extends AbstractValidator {

LegacyObject o;

@Override
void validate(){
 //validate legacy class object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also write a little utility class which provides implementation of the "obtain validator" and "collect errors" .